# No plain text passwords in Spring Boot’s application.properties

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Having something like

> security.user.password = plainTextPassword

inside Spring Boot’s `application.properties` is obviously an anti-pattern as it prevents the code from being pushed to a public SCM. In my non-Spring Boot projects I use

> security.user.password = ${myPasswordFromMavenSettingsXML}

and put a corresponding `<properties/>` reference inside my `pom.xml`.
Using Maven’s resource filter plugin the passwords are replaced at build time so the application have access to actual plain text passwords after it has been build and deployed.

For some reason Maven’s resource filter plugin does not work in this case. Is there a way to *not commit plain text passwords to an SCM* and let Spring Boot to insert them at build time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring boot has multiple mechanisms to provided [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). Some examples are command line arguments, environment variables and also application properties outside of your packaged JAR.

What I usually do:

Locally we configured several environment variables. Most (if not all) IDE's allow you to configure environment variables from within the run configuration.

For example if you don't want to expose the `spring.datasource.password` property you could set an environment variable called `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD`.

When we deploy on another environment, we usually choose to add another application.properties or application.yml file within the same folder as the application JAR/WAR, since Spring boot picks that up as well.

---

Another solution is to use [Spring cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) since it has a [config servic](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config)e which can be used as a microservice to provide configuration. The configuration can be versioned using SCM as well, but you can put it on a separate system that is not connected to your source code.

Comment: Using `-DSECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=password` worked but I choose to put my confidential properties inside `config/application.properties` also to work with different profiles. Additionally I use `${random.value}` as values in regular `application.properties` and supplying the `SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD` environment variable via Maven profiles’ for actual deployments to production environments.

Comment: To work with different profiles I just have multiple run configurations in my IDE, every one with different environment variables.

Comment: this is what can be done locally but how to do that on a remote server where no configuration data files can be deployed. Therefore I cannot select something like `produdction-profile.properties`.